# Show DateTime in ASP.NET MVC 4

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am making a small app and I need to show the DateTime, but I don't know how.

I have a ViewModel:

```
public class ViewModel
{
    public DateTime Time{ get; set; }
}
```

I have a controller called TimeController:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    ViewModel v = new ViewModel();
    v.Time = DateTime.Now;
    return View(v);
}
```

And a View from Index:

```
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}
<h2>Hello</h2>
```

Can somebody explain me how I can show the time on my view?

Comment: BTW you do understand that it will be current *server* time?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Can somebody explain me how i can show the time in my view?

You can directly show it using @:

```
<div>@DateTime.Now.ToString()</div>
```

If your only purpose is to show DateTime, I wouldn't bother using ViewModel or atleast wouldn't store DateTime.Now just to be able to display it in View.

Comment: Will this show the local time, regardless of a user's timezone?

Answer (score 3):

First line of your view

```
@model ViewModel
```

This means that your view is typed with type `ViewModel`

Then

```
@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.Time)
```

Answer (score 1):

Add first in Index View on the top this:@model Yourapp.Models.ViewModel
Then you can do this:

```
Time is : @Model.Time
```